# How to express in Modern C++ the referes-to relationship without expressing ownership?

Tags: c++, pointers, reference, smart-pointers

Starting from the "one should not use raw pointers" idiom point of view, I was looking at smart pointers to find which one best fits the refers-to relationship.

By refers-to relationship, I mean the same as this code:

```
class A
{
public:

    A(B & b) : 
        m_refB( b ) 
    {   }

private:

    B & m_refB;    // A refers to B
};
```

But without all the drawbacks of using references (cannot be later binded, cannot be reassigned, A can no longer be default constructible etc).

Every smart pointer however, in its own semantic is expressing an ownership concept. They are even named around this ownership concept (unique pointer when the ownership is unique to only one object, shared pointer when the ownership is shared amongst more objects etc).

I would like to express that A is referring to B, but A does not own B.
Can `std::reference_wrapper< B >` do the job, or that would be a wrong usage of it?

Comment: `std::weak_ptr` don't own the ownership

Comment: @Danh Doesn't `std::weak_ptr` enforce a requirement to use `std::shared_ptr` for the same resource?

Comment: @JamesAdkison, it does and this is why I do not advocate it for this. See my answer.

Comment: Yes, it does. However, it should be good in some case to use weak_ptr for checking its state is valid or not

Comment: And I also recommend the [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34440222/4505712) of SergeyA

Comment: See also [observer_ptr](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/observer_ptr).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There is no such thing as *'one should not use raw pointers'*. It is *'one should not use **owning** raw pointers'*. There is nothing wrong with having a raw pointer for refers-to idiom. Smart pointers are just an overkill for this. Especially `std::weak_ptr` :)

Comment: But a raw pointer looks like it might be a bad smell.
The reader cant distinguish bad/lazy/leaky code from the intention of an assignable/nullabale/non-owning reference.

I wish i could find in GSL non_owning<T>.

Answer (score 1):

This is what a [`std::weak_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/weak_ptr) is for.  It expresses that it refers to something but it does not own it and that thing may go away before the object referring to it goes away.

If you decide you need the referred to object you can use [`lock()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/weak_ptr/lock) which will return a [shared_ptr](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr) to the object and extend the lifetime of it until the `shared_ptr` goes out of scope.

Comment: ...but does temporarily own the object while it's actually examining it.

Comment: What's even worse, it requires a shared_ptr to exist somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

I think the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34440222/4505712) provided by [@SergeyA](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5245033/sergeya) is great and voted for it myself.

However, if you truly don't want to see raw pointers in the code then you can always create a wrapper class that is used to communicate the desired semantics.

For example:

```
/**
 * A class that refers to an existing object instance. This class does not own
 * the existing object instance and the lifetime of the existing object instance
 * must be greater than the lifetime of instantiations of this class.
 */
template<typename T>
class Handle
{
public:
    Handle(T& object) : mObject(&object) {}

    // ... other functions necessary to use this object ...

private:
    T* mObject;
};
```

Comment: But we already have [`std::reference_wrapper`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/reference_wrapper). Or is it too heavy?

Comment: @LogicStuff I cannot answer. I'm just not fully aware of all the new `C++` stuff so perhaps I've unintentionally reinvented the wheel. Thanks, I'll take a look at `std::reference_wrapper`.

Comment: There's also [`observer_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/observer_ptr), although I don't know if it will make it into the standard library.